# Date json Object json in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have json result which contain set of json objects.I could not get json object because json object is in integer value.Here is my json result

```
[{
    "serverdatetime": "2016-09-23 12:21:31",
    "game_result_array": {
        "2016-09-23": [{
            "eShowOnHome": "Yes",
            "dModifiedDate": "2016-09-22",
            "eText": "No",
            "eTodayGame": "No",
            "eDelay": "No",
            "eInvert": "None",
            "eResultOrder": "No",
            "iHGameID": "56444",
            "iGameID": "120",
            "vGameTitle": "Gana M\u00e1s",
            "eStats": "Yes",
            "vUrl": "gana-mas-loteria-nacional",
            "vGameLogo": "https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/cdn.kiskooloterias.com\/dominicanas\/upload\/game_logo\/120\/loteria-nacional-dominicana.jpg",
            "companymodifieddate": "2011-12-19 13:35:54",
            "vCompanyLogo": "https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/cdn.kiskooloterias.com\/dominicanas\/upload\/company\/76\/1373805675_loteria-nacional.jpg",
            "gamemodifieddate": "2016-01-05",
            "iCompanyID": "76",
            "vCompanyName": "Loter\u00eda Nacional",
            "vCompanyurl": "loteria-nacional-resultados",
            "dLastLotteryDate": "2016-09-22",
            "tScore": "28 01 96"
        }]
    },
    "company_ids": "75,76,77,78,84",
    "game_ids": "93,94,95,96,98,127,92,111,120,131,100,101,102,114,117,108,171,172",
    "success": "1",
    "message": "Record found"
}]
```

Here is the code what i tried

```
$http({
                        url : baseUrl,
                        method :'Post',
                        data : param
                    }) 
                    .success(function (result) {  
            $scope.rank =result.game_result_array["2016-09-23"].eShowOnHome;  

}
```

Is there anyway to get json objects? help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: `$scope.rank = result[0].game_result_array["2016-09-23"][0].eShowOnHome`

Comment: result is an array.

Comment: I took a habit to avoid such time-void issues : even if I made the back-end myself, always `console.dir()` or `console.log()` the response of any HTTP query, that way, I know exactly where's the variable I want to show

Comment: thanks @JohanKarlsson Its working perfectly:))

Answer (score 1):

`game_result_array` is an **array**, so you need to specify the **index**.

This should work fine.

```
$scope.rank =result.game_result_array["2016-09-23"][0].eShowOnHome;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast variable that are meant to be integer, Because When Calling From The endpoint, the json with integer types will be shown as strings.

> example below shows how you do that using laravel/lumen

```
$x = Data::all();  
  return (int)$x->price;
```

> hope you get the idea

Comment: Your answer is also not clear enough.check your words spelling carefully.Thanks